# Using a custom domain for uploading and downloading from an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I seem to be having issues when using a subdomain on a domain I own to upload and downloading files in an S3 bucket.

When testing with the real domain using the s3 cli, we have no issues creating and using pre-signed urls to upload or download. Similarly, generating multipart upload IDs for large files also works fine.

Example multipart upload call that works fine

```bash
(env3) vienna@ue-ds06:~/vienna$ aws s3api create-multipart-upload --bucket ****** --key test
Bucket: *********
Key: test
ServerSideEncryption: AES256
UploadId: *****************************
(env3) vienna@ue-ds06:~/vienna$
```

Same call with the endpoint instead pointing to a domain we own, that has a CNAME to the cloudfront distribution. The bucket is just the bucket name, while the endpoint url is of the form https://..com

```bash
(env3) vienna@ue-ds06:~/vienna$ aws s3api create-multipart-upload --bucket ****** --key test --endpoint-url ******

An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

Heres the cloudfront configuration. As you can see in the screenshots, cloudfront signing is disabled, caching is off, and the distribution is configured to send headers and query params to the origin. I've also tried different custom configurations for which headers to send and they all appear to have no effect in the signing.

[image: Origin config, with s3 bucket redacted]
[image: Origin config continued]
[image: Behaviour]
[image: Origin access config]

I'm not sure if using cloudfront like so is the way to go about this, or if theres something else in AWS that can support this use case.

Is this just not possible due to cloudfront injecting a header on the request to the origin, that ends up messing up the signature calc on the S3?

The end goal here is to use boto3 to sign urls that can be used to upload or download files using our custom domain, instead of using the full s3 domain. Uploads in particular can either be through a single upload, or chunked using multipart uploads. In the later case we use boto3 to generate an upload id, and then N upload urls that have the upload id added.

Comment: What are you using `--endpoint-url` for? That's for specifying S3-compatible interfaces like MinIO. Passing your custom domain there would be incorrect. And is the question regarding multi part uploads or presigned URLs? These 2 actions differ. Can you please update the question to focus on one?

Comment: I figured `--endpoint-url` was the arg used when using a cloudfront distribution as the target. As for multi part or presigned, in my case they're similar, just that multipart would be used prior to generating a presigned url using boto3, then the upload id would be included as a param when generating presigned urls to upload.